Calling mockResolvedValue works once in first test, not in second test
I'm trying to mock PostgreSQL (pg) in Jest and I don't understand what is going on with the mocking.
My code is extremely similar, if not the same as the answer in How to Mock postgresql (pg) in node.js using jest
except that I'm using Pool instead of Client. I've spent a lot of time trying to research and understand the problem, such as maybe it's due to Jest 'hoisting' if that's relevant, but I couldn't understand nor figure it out.
My main issue is that I have 2 tests. test1 passes completely fine, no issues at all and I think it is mocking correctly, but the second time I call pool.query.mockResolvedValue, which is in a separate test2, it errors out giving me TypeError: pool.query.mockResolvedValue is not a function
In test1, I'd like to clarify my function calls query multiple times, and so needs that to have a mocked value several times. Same for test2. I could just move all the code I want under test1 and that does since of course test1 always worked, but I think that'd ruin the readability a lot and wouldn't really be clean to have everything under a singular it('test1').
To my understanding this should work as it does in the Stack Overflow link I sent above without using any other methods like spyOn, right?
I put it in the comments of the code below, but I've tried removing import, and removing the clearAllMocks in the afterEach but it still errors out the same way.
index.test.ts:
import { Pool } from "pg";
// I read somewhere that importing jest doesn't really matter in a jest file so even without this line, the same error occurred
import { jest, describe, it, beforeEach, afterEach } from "@jest/globals" 
// Also using sinon but I don't think that's relevant
import * as sinon from "sinon"

jest.mock("pg", () => {
  const mPool= {
    connect: jest.fn(),
    query: jest.fn(),
    end: jest.fn(),
  };
  return { Pool: jest.fn(() => mPool) };
});


describe('test', () => {
  let pool;
  beforeEach(() => {
    pool= new Pool();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    // I've tried to remove this clearAllMocks line too, but it did nothing and still same error.
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  it('test1', async () => {
    const expectedQueryResult = [{"test": 5 }]
    const mockedQuery = pool.query.mockResolvedValue({ rows: [], expectedQueryResult });
    
    // assertions for testing function expecting to pass, they do pass fine
    
    mockedQuery .mockImplementationOnce((a,b) => {
      throw new Error('test error')
    });
    try {
      await testFunction()
      sinon.assert.fail()
    } catch (error) {
      sinon.assert.match(error, 'test error')
    }

    // This whole test passes

  });

  it('test2', async () => {
    const expectedQueryResult = [{"test": 5 }]
    pool.query.mockResolvedValue({ rows: [], expectedQueryResult });
    // more code for this test below, but I error out with the above line.
    // TypeError: pool.query.mockResolvedValue is not a function
  });
});



Do you have mock resetting or clearing in your Jest config? Please give a [mre].

My jest config files contains like testRegex, collectCoverage, but nothing close to resetMocks or clearMocks boolean.
